# onMarkerClick function and setting animation on camera

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am using map v2. I would like to change camera position with animation when user click on a marker.

but when I use below function and I click on a marker,title of that marker is not displayed! 
(Just place the camera is changed).

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(v.getPosition())      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(13)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(45)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(10)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    return true;
}
```

Comment: just add `v.showInfoWindow();` to that code

Comment: plz post your answer.